# Laravel migration problem : Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in l

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I make the same data type for both of that table but there is a problem. But for another table I didn't get any error. what is the problem behind?
[image]
[image]
**General error: 1005 Can't create table `meal_system`.`amounts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `amounts` add constraint `amounts_member_id_foreign` foreign key (`member_id`) references `members` (`member_id`) on delete cascade)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to migrate members before amounts table case your foreign is with member_id to migrate members first just change the date of the migration file to be before the amount

For example :

```
2021_01_01_000000_create_members_table

2021_02_02_100000_create_amounts_table
```